# calling function pointer of a member function from a function pointer vector

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers, event-driven-design

i think this is mostly a syntax error ( though not captured during compilation, only at runtime does the error happen)

i am trying to develop an event driven architecture , where i keep a vector of eventReceiver and try to call them from the vector.

**CommonIO.h**

```
    class CommonIO {
    public:
        typedef void (*incomingMsgReceiver)(char*);
            void registerForIncomingMsg(incomingMsgReceiver);
            void incomingMsgReceived(char*);
    }
```

**CommonIO.cpp**

```
    std::vector<void (*)(char*)> listeners;

    void CommonIO::registerForIncomingMsg(incomingMsgReceiver receiverFunction) {
        listeners.push_back(receiverFunction);
    }

    void CommonIO::incomingMsgReceived(char* buf) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < listeners.size(); j++) {
                listeners[i](buf);  //error, segmentation fault..how do i call it?
            }
    }
```

**Main.h**

```
class Main {
public:
     static void msgReceived(char*);
     void mainLoop();

}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
void Main::msgReceived(char* msg)
{
    printf("\n\n --------->>>>> %s \n\n" , msg);
}

void Main::mainLoop()
{
     CommonIO::incomingMsgReceiver receiver = &Main::msgReceived;
     CommonIO::getInstance()->registerForIncomingMsg( receiver );
}
```

incomingMsgReceived function is called by an asynchronous process

the program compiles fine..however breaks down at : listenersi;  line.
what is the proper syntax for this ?

Comment: I've no idea how you can get a segmentation fault inside `CommonIO::incomingMsgReceived` when this function is never called.

Comment: I don't believe that's your real code (what is `i`?).  Please consider creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: In your `incomingMsgReceived`, what's the name of the argument, where does `buf` come from, and why does it need casting?

Comment: What is buf? Or i for that matter?

Comment: hi you guys are right..this is part of a quite large program..and difficult to paste the whole thing here.

however, i have edited the code a bit for better understanding.

- incomingMsgReceived is called asynchronously by another process.
- buf is the received msg that is to be passed along   

however,all these works, except the call to listeners[i](buf); which is where i am not using proper syntax ( most likely ).

Comment: Look at that function again. The loop uses `unsigned int j`, but you're indexing the array using `i`. You either have a typo there, or you have a higher-scoped variable called `i`.

Comment: arghh..you are absolutely correct..thats what caused the issue! thankyouthankyou!

Comment: A syntax error not captured by compilation? There is no such thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use inheritance and a common base class? Makes simpler code and also you are detailing with objects so you have data, other methods etc.

i.e. something like this

```
class incomingMsgReceiver {
   public:
      virtual void msgReceived(char *msg) = 0;
};

class MyMessage : public incomingMsgReceiver {
   public virual void msgReceieved(char *msg);
}

class OtherMyMessage : public incomingMsgReceiver {
   public virual void msgReceieved(char *msg);
}

void MyMessage::msgReceived(char *msg)
{
   /// Do stuff here

}

void msgReceived::OtherMyMessage(char *msg)
{
   /// Do stuff here

}
```

Then for your `common.h`:

```
class CommonIO
{
   private:
      std::vector<incomingMsgReceiver *> listeners;
   public:
      void addListner(incomingMsgReceiver *reveiver) { listners.push_back(reveiver); }

      void incomingMsgReceived(char*msg)
      {
         for (unsigned int j = 0; j < listeners.size(); j++)
         {
            listeners[j]->msgReceived((msg);
         }
      }
};
```

Comment: the error was pointed out correctly  by  DCoder . the problem was a very silly index issue. however, before i noticed his reply..i also tried out your suggestion and this also works fine!